# Confused about double spending

Tags: corda

How do notary services avoid double spending behind the scenes? I have gone through the Consensus document on the Corda website. What exactly does double spending mean? How does the current banking system achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Double-spending is an attempt to transfer a digital asset twice (e.g. send the same Bitcoin to Alice and Bob).

Notaries prevent double-spending by maintaining a set of spent (transaction hash, output index) pairs. When a new transaction comes in, the notary checks whether the (transaction hash, output index) pair is already in its set:

- If it is, it refuses to sign the transaction
- If it isn't, it signs the transaction and adds the (transaction hash, output index) to its set to mark it as spent